# About multiply by constant of LWE

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, lwe

I am new to lattice-based cryptography

May I ask that for a lattice-based encryption

$$enc(m) = A^{T}R+m \bmod q$$

If I set the $q$ to be able to decrypt to $m$ (and suppose the bound of $q$ is tight over the bound of error and secret chosen from LWE)

But if I need an operation that takes a constant $p$, and multiply $p\cdot enc(m)$

Does it mean that all I need to do is to have a new bound of $q$ equals $p\cdot q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that this situation becomes easier to understand if you make the various parts of lattice-based encryption more explicit.

An LWE encryption

$$[A, \vec b := A\vec s + \vec m + \vec e]$$

may be approximately decrypted to $\vec m+ \vec e$
by computing $\vec b - A\vec s$.
To isolate $\vec m$, we require a separate error-tolerant encoding, e.g. we instead have our ciphertext be of the form

$$[A, \vec b' := A\vec s + \mathsf{encode}(\vec m)+\vec e]$$

where $\mathsf{encode}(\vec m)$ is such that we can efficiently compute

$$\vec m':=\mathsf{encode}(\vec m)+\vec e\mapsto \vec m$$

A common way to do this is to write (when $p\mid q$)

$$\mathsf{encode}(\vec m) = (q/p)\vec m,$$
where we can decode

$$\vec m'\mapsto \lfloor \vec m'/(q/p)\rceil = \lfloor \vec m + \frac{\vec e}{q/p}\rceil$$

provided $\lVert e / (q/p)\rVert_\infty < 1/2$ one can then show that this is equal to $\vec m$, e.g. we have correctly decrypted.

If we naively multiply by some scalar $c$, then the error $\vec e$ becomes the (potentially larger) value $c\vec e$, and the condition

$$\lVert e/(q/p)\rVert_\infty < 1/2\iff \lVert \vec e\rVert_\infty < \frac{q}{2p}$$

becomes the condition

$$\lVert c\vec e\rVert_\infty < \frac{q}{2p}\iff \lVert e\rVert_\infty < \frac{q}{2pc}.$$

As you say, setting $q' := cq$ is one way to compensate for this.

---

It is worth mentioning there is another way to multiply by large constants with low noise growth in LWE-based encryption, namely using *gadgets*.
See [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/086.pdf) for a formal introduction.
The main idea is as follows.
Write

$$\mathsf{Enc}(\vec m;\vec e) = [A, A\vec s + \mathsf{encode}(\vec m) + \vec e]$$

One can prove that this is linearly homomorphic, in the sense that

$$\mathsf{Enc}(\vec m_0;\vec e_0) + \mathsf{Enc}(\vec m_1;\vec e_1) = \mathsf{Enc}(\vec m_0+\vec m_1;\vec e_0+\vec e_1)$$
and
$$c\cdot \mathsf{Enc}(\vec m;\vec e) = \mathsf{Enc}(c\cdot\vec m;c\cdot \vec e).$$

So we can multiply by $c$, but grow errors by $c$ as well.
Instead, if we "encrypt $\vec m$ using a gadget", meaning create the collection of ciphertexts

$$\{\mathsf{Enc}(2^i\vec m; \vec e_i)\}_{i},$$

then we can rewrite (for $c = \sum_i c_i2^i$ the binary decomposition of $c$)

$$c\cdot m = \sum_{i}c_i2^im = c_i\sum_i m2^i$$

It follows that we can compute

$$\sum_i c_i\cdot \mathsf{Enc}(2^im;\vec e_i) = \mathsf{Enc}(c\cdot\vec m; \sum_i c_i\cdot\vec e_i)$$

E.g. we can multiply by an arbitrary $c\in\mathbb{Z}_q$ while increasing errors by a factor $\approx \log_2 q$.
More generally, if we decompose $c$ modulo $B$, the noise growth becomes $\approx (B/2)\log_B q$, e.g. we can achieve noise growth $\ll q$ by increasing the size of our ciphertexts by a small amount.

Comment: Maybe this answer needs to include the meaning of $\lceil x \rfloor$ as the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $q$ as the ciphertext modulus, then you would want the new ciphertext $p \cdot Enc(m)$ to also lie in $\mathbb{Z}_q$, which means the result will still be obtained mod $q$. Multiplication of the ciphertext with a constant is a case of homomorphic multiplication usually considered in homomorphic encryption schemes.